# Error while using function from car package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a few functions from car package, but while when starting the function (e.g. scatterplotMatrix or bcPower) I get a message "could not find function "scatterplotMatrix""

I I removed and installed package, updated R Studio and I still have the same problem.

A few lines from my code:

```r
d <- read.csv2("World.csv") 
d1 <- d[,c(1,16,25,27,47,56,57,58,59,70)] 
d1 <- d1[complete.cases(d1), ]  
scatterplotMatrix(d1[,2:9],smooth = FALSE)
```

I get:

```
Error in scatterplotMatrix(d1[, 2:9], smooth = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "scatterplotMatrix"
```

Comment: Did you load `car` ie call `library(car)` before using it? This works for me `car::scatterplotMatrix(mtcars[,1:4])`

Comment: Yes. I've  found a solution. I used ```update.package(checkBuilt = TRUE)``` and again installed and loaded car package. Now it works.